# Postgres SQL: How to query jsonb column having data in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `customrule` with a structure

```
id.       - int
name      - varchar
actions.  - jsonb
```

I already have read about the  `->` operator. But it seems not working in my case as I have data stored in as an array.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name | Id | Actions                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CR-1 | 1  | [{"name": "Action1", "count": "1"},{"name": "Action2", "count": "2"}] |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| CR-2 | 2  | [{"name": "Action5", "count": "1"},{"name": "Action4", "count": "2"}] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CR-3 | 3  | [{"name": "Action1", "count": "1"},{"name": "Action1", "count": "2"}] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to query this data and get all records which have `Action1` used in the `actions` column. Which should return `row 1 and 3rd` as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the contains operator with an array parameter

```
select id, name, actions
from customrule 
where actions @> '[{"name": "Action1"}]'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b404d223e332b3f4193e43945517d1e8)